# Separating same ID value between location in data-set using Python

Tags: python, data-science

I have a data-set that contains experimental data by location and alphanumeric ID. There are several different locations and several different ID's at each location. Each ID-location pair receives its own row in the csv. Not every location has every ID. There is a core set of ID's that can be found at every single location in the data-set that I am interested in locating. A simple list of the ID's found at each location would be perfect. There are ~20 different locations and ~1000 different ID's distributed across those locations with about 12,000 total experiments. A sample looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bfVx.png)

Initially, I tried to create a pivot table of ID's by location that I could then determine a way to sort, but since the ID's are not numeric, this didn't seem to work. I then tried to create lists of every ID at each location. If I were successful in creating these lists, would there be a way to filter them to find the common ID's at every location? Or could there be a more straightforward method from the beginning?

Comment: Hi, I think it is useful if you give some piece of data to help with the error reproducibility. 
If its possible, you can also show what is the expected result from your code.

Comment: You said that each ID-location pair receives its own row in the csv. Does that means that the id and location information are in the same row? I mean, you have like "B13-Loc1"? Then as you don't have id for all data you can have some "Loc3" info for ID-Location column?

Comment: Hi @iurysimoes-sousa I updated the post if you would be willing to look. Thanks

Comment: @g-ret3 Do not forget marking the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but I used `groupby` to get is grouped in list of `unique` values:

First, I have to generate a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 30
letters = np.array(['A','B'])
locs = np.array(['THX','IAH'])
year = np.random.randint(2013,2016,n)
ids = np.array([letters[np.random.randint(0,len(letters))]+str(np.random.randint(1,100)) for i in range(n)])
locations = np.array([locs[np.random.randint(0,len(locs))]+str(np.random.randint(1,5)) for i in range(n)])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([year,locations,ids]).T,columns=['Year','Location','id'])
```

Then you can do:

```
In: df['id'].groupby(df['Location']).apply(lambda L: np.unique(L))

Out:
Location
IAH1                                     [A18, A45, B5]
IAH3                                    [A17, B12, B59]
IAH4                          [A84, A86, B27, B43, B87]
THX1    [A48, A51, A6, A72, A8, A82, B23, B4, B66, B78]
THX2                     [A25, A41, A49, A58, B13, B39]
THX3                                    [A26, A63, B61]
Name: id, dtype: object
```